# I get a segmentation fault before entering main()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

These are my included libraries:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int sockfd;
```

This is my thread for the `send` command:

```
void *mySend(void* a)
{ 
    cout<<"me too"<<endl;
        //this cout is not printed.

    char message[100];

    while (1)
    { 
         cin>>message;
    send(sockfd, message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
    }
    return NULL;    

 }
```

My main function connects this code to the server and has the `recv` command for receiving from the server.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     cout << "hello" << endl;
     //this cout is not printed
 int port;

     cout << "hello" << endl;

     sscanf(argv[3],"%d", & port);

 cout << "hello" << endl;

 struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
     dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     dest_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
     dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
     memset(&(dest_addr.sin_zero),'\0',8);

     int c = connect (sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr,sizeof(structsockaddr));
     if (c!=-1)
         cout <<"CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY!"<<endl;

 char buffer [20];
 pthread_t mammad;
 pthread_create (&mammad, NULL,mySend,0);
```

While for the `recv` command.

```
     while(1)
 {
     recv (sockfd , buffer , strlen(buffer)+1 , 0 );
     cout <<"server said :" <<buffer<<endl;
 } 
 close (sockfd);
 return 0;

 }
```

I get a segmentation fault before anything being printed.
I just cant figure this out.
help!

Comment: have you tried using a debugger to get a backtrace and position of wheer it crashes?

Comment: i would strongly recomend checking `argc` before accessing `argv`. e.g., in your case `if (argc < 4) { cout << "not enough args"; return -1;} sscanf(argv[3],"%d", & port);`

Comment: Do you have any static or global declarations?

Comment: Follow the usual debugging tactics: Remove stuff until the problem goes away. The last thing you removed must have been part of the problem. Post **minimal** compileable code when asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

If the program crashes before entering `main` it must be some initialization stuff that is crashing. You should take a look at your global objects and their constructors. When doing so keep in mind that you might have problems if global object 1 depends on global object 2 already being constructed.

Comment: The infamous `Static Initialization Fiasco`.

Answer (score 3):

In what way you are giving your input.

If it is like

$./a.out PORT_NO

Then you will deffinitely get segentation.Because you are using **argv[3]**

If you do it for **argv[1]** it will definitely run

I have tested it.

The output are as follows....

```
[sharma@localhost ~]$ ./a.out 5000
hello
hello
5000
hello
CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY!
me too
server said :W
server said :el
server said :com
server said :e to�H*����
server said : TCPServer����
me too
me too
me too
me too
me too
It's a test
server said :No one on that ro
me too
server said :le.No one on that 
server said :role. one on that 
me too
me too
```

Oh...  the send and receive is broken.because i used your pthread in recv while loop.